# Simple arithmetic functions in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I am starting to get acquainted with the use of ELK for work purposes, but struggle to find a solution to use simple mathematic requests in my database.
As shown on the picture, my DB contains 16 available fields, but I would like to create others, without doing it on Excel before converting my file in CVS again.
For example, I would like to create a variable #Bugs/Release. I've heard that this is quite easy to make with no need of scripting, but I can't find the way to do it... Has anybody the solution of this problem?

Huge thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/055Hr.png)

Comment: what math operations do you want , what is the query , what did you try ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.